# Get URL from middleware

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using python and the Google App Engine. I've added a Middleware class to my code, which is working fine. But now i need to know which URL is called in the Middleware class. I'm don't know how to get the URL from there.

This is what i have:

```
class OtherClasses(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        # some code...
    def post(self):
        # some code...

class Middleware(object):   
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        #logging.debug("Setting namespace..." + namespace)

        print(self.request.url) #<--- Doesn't work in here...?


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([ROUTES], debug=True, config=webapp2_config)
app = Middleware(app)
```

Appearently the **self.request.url** doesn't work in the middleware class. Anyone any idea how i can get the URL (or the route) that i'm currently in??

Comment: @ShayErlichmen Yes, none of them are available in the Middleware class

Comment: @ShayErlichmen Not working either

Comment: I'm guessing, but how about self.app.request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

path = os.environ['PATH_INFO']
```

Comment: Accessing the CGI environment in `os.path` directly breaks abstraction and is a bad idea, particularly when the WSGI environment is so easily available.

Comment: THanks, this is actually the only code that seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

`self.request` doesn't work because `self` refers to your middleware object in this instance, not the request handler. Your middleware doesn't construct a request object, so it's not available.

The `environ` variable is a [WSGI environment](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/), which is an extension of a CGI environment, and as such, parts of the URL are stored in several variables, including `PATH_INFO` and `QUERY_STRING`.

The easiest way to get a familiar object is probably to construct your own webob request object, like this:

```
request = webob.Request(environ)
```

Now you can access `request.url` etc as you would expect; just take care with accessing POST data in your middleware, as that will read the same input stream your handler expects to read; if you want to do this, you'll need to jump through extra hoops.